# Возможно ли осуществить проверку на поддержку браузером let, и создать псевдоним на var?

Tags: javascript

Вопреки документации, переменные с блочной видимостью, объявленные с помощью `let` работают только начиная с `Firefox 44` и `Chromium 49`.
При этом браузер (`Chrome 47`) прочитав конструкцию `let=` выдаёт ошибку в и останавливают выполнение всех сценариев.

1 Как распознать, работает ли браузер с блочными переменными `let` не прибегая к парсингу `userAgent`-а?

2 Я уже молчу про эмуляцию `let`, но можно ли создать/переопределить `alias` на `var`, если браузер не умеет работать с `let`?

3 Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы блочные переменные `let` работали на более старых версиях `Chromium` и на `Samsung Internet`?

Comment: let и var отличаются не только буквами, но и поведением.

Comment: Лично я просто до сих пор юзаю везде var, а вообще обычно для таких вещей используют babel

Comment: @andreymal Пол года назад делал также, пока не столкнувшись с классическим непониманием работы кучи и замыкания, не узнал про `let`, переписав весь код с использованием только `let`, но сегодня обнаружил, о чём писал выше. Переписать всё на `var` возможно, но не охота прибегать к этому, не поинтересовавшись у более опытных людей об альтернативах.

Comment: Более опытные люди юзают babel) Но лично я его не люблю

Comment: @andreymal не юзать новые удобные фичи ES стандарта скорее глупость, чем "не люблю". Скорее вы не сталкиваетесь с нужным функционалом, и пишите примитивы типа hello world

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев синтаксический сахар ES6 — это сахар, без которого жить можно, а для многих других фич (промисы, fetch и т. п.) есть полифиллы аж под IE8) Пишу всякий сложный фронтенд на ES5, нервы в порядке, брат жив))

Comment: @andreymal Можете рассказать по подробнее что такое Babel, для чего он предназначен, как его использовать, и как он поможет конкретно в моих задачах?

Comment: Это такая фиговина для сервера, которая хитрым образом преобразует современный ES6 код в старый ES5, благодаря чему можно писать всякие let и не бояться, что это не заработает в старых браузерах. Но полноценный ответ пусть кто-нибудь другой пишет, сам я Babel не юзаю) https://babeljs.io

Comment: @andreymal вы пишете SPA? или берете готовые плагины jquery и вставляете на страницу? А то это немного не "сложный frontend". ES6 есть сахар, но много и фич. Именно фич. Если бы вы реально занимались сложным фронтендом этого разговора не возникло бы. То что все можно писать как в 2012 это понятно, но зачем? Стоять на месте при росте технологий по вашему хорошо? Не использовать их тоже ерунда, это говорит о том, что вы не хотите учиться вот и все) Я бы рекомендовал пересмотреть ваш взгляд на такие вещи.

Comment: @IlyaIndigo по теме лишь напишу, что вам можно зайти сюда https://learn.javascript.ru/let-const и почитать зачем все эти let и const нужны. Все дело в контроле кода, чем больше контроля, тем проще жизнь программиста. В вашем случае абсолютно не требуется заменять `var` на `let`. А вот при редактировании кода очень удобно писать "правильный" код, с верными областями видимости и т.д. Если вам нужно писать код с новой спецификацией, но воспроизводить на всех браузерах, как уже подмечено выше, вам нужен `babel`. "это удобно это красиво" :)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев да, SPA в том числе. Но рассказы о том, что как я пишу и почему без babel, это уже не по теме вопроса, лучше в чат какой-нибудь переехать если интересно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**

```
<script type="application/javascript">
<!--
    'use strict';
    try{eval('let test');}catch(e)
    {
        alert('К сожалению, Ваш браузер, морально устарел и не поддерживается нами. :-(\n\nПожалуйста, используйте актуальные и безопасные версии современных браузеров:\n\nFirefox: https://getfirefox.com\n\nChrome: https://google.com/chrome\n\nПри закрытии этого окна вас перенаправит на страницу загрузки браузера Firefox.\n\nПожалуйста, установите или обновите этот браузер, используя подсказки установщика, и обязательно возвращайтесь к нам! :-)\n\n'+location+'\n\n');
        location='https://getfirefox.com';
    }
//-->
</script>
```

**2** Нельзя определить псевдоним или ссылку на синтаксическую конструкцию в `JavaScript`.

**3** Возможно, с помощью директивы **'use strict';** заставить понимать блочные переменные `let` на браузерах `Chromium 41+` и `Samsung Internet 4`, а также позволить интерпретатору `JavaScript` ещё лучше оптимизировать код.

Подробнее: [Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) и [let support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=let)